# Dynamically modifying DataGridView rows

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, datagridview

When I load up a certain page in my GUI I'm trying to get my datagridview to dynamically refresh itself with new data that it might've received on a tcp socket. This is how I am currently trying to refresh the data however it just adds new rows to the existing data prior to loading the page.

```
myGridView.DataSource = null;

myGridView.Rows.Add(//data);
```

I've also tried doing it this way to refresh the screen with data:

```
myGridView.Rows.Clear()

myGridView.Rows.Add(//data);
```

How do you update the DataGridView by first clearing whatevers in the dri

Answer (score 2):

You might need to `Refresh` the Grid like

```
myGridView.Rows.Clear();
myGridView.Columns.Clear();

myGridView.DataBindings.Clear();
YourDataSet.Clear();

myGridView.DataSource = null;
myGridView.DataMember = null;

myGridView.Refresh();
```

A DataGridView sets up bindings the first time you assign the DataSource. The problem is that subsequent DataSource assignments, if the assignments have a different structure from the initial assignment, will fail because the bindings are now "off" you can have a look at [How to Reset a DataGridView](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/256055/how-to-reset-a-datagridview) for more info

Comment: Refreshing the grid doesn't do anything.

Comment: Rows are still being added to the old data.

Comment: Then probably you need to show more code of yours. how are you filling in data in the DGV